# Check if inputs in register form is existing in a table in database

Tags: php, html

So this is my code so far. I'm new in programming in php so I was trying my best to make a register form that checks if the inputs exists in dummyclients_table in my database and if it exists it will insert the inputs into clients_table. Anyone who knows php can help me with this?

The process in the registration should be input>check if existing in a table in database>insert data if existing.

We are required to have a dummy table for security purposes because it is our school's system someday. We can't allow other people to just register in this system. It is exclusive for the students in our school only.

```
<?php

session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['clients_tbl'])!="")
{
header("Location: homethesis.php");
}
include_once 'dbconnect.php';
if(isset($_POST['btn-signup']))
{
$id_number = $_POST['id_number'];
$lname = $_POST['lname'];
$fname =$_POST['fname'];
$mname =$_POST['mname'];
$contact_number =$_POST['contact_number'];
$password =$_POST['password'];
$course =$_POST['course'];
$college =$_POST['college'];


$check = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM dummyclients_tbl WHERE student_number='$id_number' AND student_lname='$lname'");
```

I temporarily used this condition to see if my code is really working

```
if(mysql_num_rows($check)==0){
?>
    <script>alert('Match Found');</script>
    <?php
}
else{
?>
    <script>alert('Nothing Found');</script>
    <?php
}


}
?>
```

Comment: And what? What is wrong?

Comment: it returns me this error

Notice: Undefined variable: dbc in D:\xa\htdocs\PHPversion_thesis\Client\registerthesis.php on line 21

Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in D:\xa\htdocs\PHPversion_thesis\Client\registerthesis.php on line 21
Database Error Occured 
Warning: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, null given in D:\xa\htdocs\PHPversion_thesis\Client\registerthesis.php on line 25

Comment: Please use PHP's password handling functions. Never ever store plain text passwords!

Comment: __Edit__ your question with this info.

Comment: so my code can't it be edited anymore? or is there other solution in my problem?